# tree traversal inorder LISP

Tags: tree, lisp, common-lisp, inorder

I am trying to return the list of nodes of a tree(not necessarily binary tree) accessed inorder.

The tree is represented as a list with sublists, for example: (a (b) (c (d) (e))), b - left-subtree, (c (d) (e)) - right-subtree, a -root.
The result should be: b,a,d,c,e

This is my code, but i always seem to get the "stack overflow" error. Can someone please help me?

```
;return left-subtree
(defun left-tree(tree)
  (cond
   ((null tree) NIL)
   ((not (listp tree)) NIL)
   (t (car (cdr tree)))
  )
)

;return right-tree
(defun right-tree(tree)
  (cond
   ((null tree) NIL)
   ((not (listp tree)) NIL)
   (t (cdr (cdr tree)))
  )
)

;perform inorder
(defun inorder(tree)
  (if (not (list-length tree)) 0
  (append
   (inorder (left-tree tree))
   (list (car tree))
   (inorder (right-tree tree))
  )
 )
)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `(not (list-length tree))`? `not` of a number is always false.

Comment: The orders of tree traversals are typically pre-order (root, left, right); post-order (left, right, root); and in-order (left, root, right).  I know you posted an example of output, but what should "in-order" mean when you have more than two children?  E.g., if you have the tree (a (b) (c) (d)) what's the in-order traversal supposed to be?  a b a c a d?

Comment: One other problem is that you create a new list in each evaluation of `inorder` while you want to end up with a flat list.

The part about `car/cdr recursion` in [Common Lisp: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/) might help you.

Comment: Please format your code properly (indentation and paren placement).  As it is not, it is hardly readable.

Answer (score 3):

The infinite recursion is caused by the fact that a number is never false-y.
Replace `(not (list-length tree))` with `(null tree)`.
(That is, recurse over structure, not over size.)

Once you fix this, you will get a type error due to your base case result in `inorder` - it should be `nil`, not `0`.

Once you fix *that*, you will find another problem:

```
CL-USER> (inorder '(a (b) (c (d) (e))))
(B A (C (D) (E)))
```

This is far from correct.

If you look at the result of `right-tree`, it's not actually what you claim it should be:

```
CL-USER> (right-tree '(a (b) (c (d) (e))))
((C (D) (E)))
```

As you can see, this is a one-element list with the right subtree in it, not the right subtree.
(Testing each function in isolation is a good idea, especially if you're certain that they're correct.)

The root is the first list item (the `car`), the left subtree is the second (the `car` of the `cdr` - `cadr`), and the right subtree is the third *item* (the `car` of the `cdr` of the `cdr` - `caddr`), not the rest of the list starting at the third item as you wrote.
You need to extract the subtree:

```
(defun right-tree(tree)
  (cond
    ((null tree) NIL)
    ((not (listp tree)) NIL)
    (t (caddr tree))))

CL-USER> (inorder '(a (b) (c (d) (e))))
(B A D C E)
```